# Как заменить картинку в TextView программно

Tags: android

Есть кнопка (`TextView`) и у ней нужно заменить изображение - как это делается программно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textView_item_currency"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPanel"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_question_mark"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:text="@string/currency"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: удалил лишние комментарии и оформил как ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы программно изменять картинку у `TextView` используйте:

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,
     getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_dogecoin),null,null)
//картинки(слева, вверху, справа, снизу)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Или

```
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: в первом варианте картинка растягивается на всю кнопку а второго нет у Button

Comment: Точно, второе у ImageButton.

Comment: Ай блин, так это даже не кнопка в вопросе, а текствью. Заголовок и метка вводят в заблуждение.